# Automating attaching to multiple processes in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

For my debugging I have to attach to many process instances:

1. The EXE for our app.
2. 5 instances of some other process (let's call it "foo").
3. 8 instances of some other process (let's call it "bar").
4. 41 instances of some other process (let's call it "Agnes" in honor of the Twilight Zone episode, "From Agnes with Love").

Rather than having to Ctrl-select all of them and then click "Attach", is there some sort of template I can define that will say?:

1. Attach to and EXE called "whatever".
2. All instances of a process called "foo".
3. All instances of a process called "bar".
4. All instances of a process called "Agnes".

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to automate it with code like:

```
foreach(Process proc in DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses)
{
    if(proc.Name.ToString().EndsWith("foo.exe"))
    {
        proc.Attach();
    }
}
```

See [Attach to specific Process shortcut in Visual Studio](http://blog.markvincze.com/attach-to-process-shortcut-in-visual-studio/) for more details.

Comment: Sergey, I just noticed that the free version doesn't support Visual Studio 2019 (ie, I didn't see 2019 for the free version but did see it for the Professional version).  The work I'm doing is for my company, so I'm not able to purchase the Professional version.  Are there any plans to release a free version for 2019?

Comment: @user3390380 The free version supports Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Sergey, sorry, I'm a little confused.  When the installer comes up, I just see checkboxes for VS 2015 and 2017, so support for 2019 isn't clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag you in my question of about 6 hours ago. @Sergey

Comment: @user3390380 Try to invoke VSIXInstaller from VS 2019 explicitly: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" VisualCommander_312.vsix